# Is there any mention in the scriptures that every God has to have a temple of his/her own?

Tags: scripture, gods, temple

Is there any mention in the scriptures that every God has to have a temple of his/her own? I'm asking this because the number of temples have increased by a very large number in the past few years.

Comment: "I'm asking this because the number of temples are ever-increasing." But that has nothing to do with what u are asking because the number of deities is fixed.

Comment: You are right. I edited it.

Comment: In Sri Ramakrishna's life story, there is a Goddess (I cannot remember), who likes to be on open field, without temple, and childrens go to sleep under murti shadow. Once, someone made a temple, but Goddess wanted to be without temple, and after sometime of bad luck, She destroy it, and luck come back again. I believe this story is in Romain Rolland book about Sri Ramakrishna.